# Overriding source files

Tags: android, libraries, ads

Overriding may not be the best term to use here, but I'll explain.

For my applications, I start with a Core library. This is where the app is, source files, assets, layouts, etc. Then, for each market (Google, Amazon, BlackBerry, etc), I create a new project, and have it depend on the core library. This allows me to have one base code to work on, without having to duplicate changes to all the other market versions.

I put things like market links in a resource file, which I simply "override" by putting the same value in the res directory of the chosen project.

I was hoping the be able to do the same thing with source files, but I get the multiple dex files error.

I'm trying to base my free version off the same core library. I have two versions to do, each with different ad providers (Google, and Amazon). I don't want to have to have the two ad libraries in the core library. My idea was to have a CustomAd class in the core library which is basically blank, and doesn't do anything. Then, in the projects that need ads, place a new CustomAd class, "overriding" the original in the core library. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I worked a little magic to get things to work. I created the CustomAd class in the core lib. There's also a public static interface in a Util class. The CustomAd runs the methods in the interface, if it is not null.

In the new launcher in the ad project, it sets the static interface, then launches the Splash screen.

This allows me to keep one core library for the app, and run different ad providers in different markets.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you migrate to Android Studio and define the configurarions in the `build.gradle` files.